# How to add row number or Serial no in laravel datatable

Tags: laravel, serialization, datatable, numbers, row

This is the bill_info table, for which i need to serialized row no like 1  2  . . . . . . . . .  . . . .n

[image]

There is data list returned, how I can get **serial_no** custom field in datatable list view.

```
    $data = BillInfo::get(['bill_info.*']);

    return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->removeColumn('id')
                    ->make(true);
```

Comment: I dont see any `serial_no` field in your database. use the id. or do you want the `invoice_no`?

Comment: serial_no field not exist in database but it will represent the record no of the given list.  There is 8 records available, so serial no will start from 1 to 8

Comment: why dont you use the id field? or just count it inside a loop and print each iteration.

Comment: Please explain further your question, i believe it can be solved quickly and nicely.

Comment: id field value started from 168 to 175 for those of record but  i need from 1 to 8 for the given record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the variable rownum at the beginning of your query. Then set the increment process in your query.

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));

$data = BillInfo::get(['bill_info.*', 
                    DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum')]);

return Datatables::of($data)
                ->removeColumn('id')
                ->make(true);
```

Here you can get rownum as serial no of the given records [1 . . . 8].

Comment: I am using order by in my query but this does not work with order by for example if I have 3 records then it is giving 4,5,6 as rownum and if i will remove order by then it is giving 1,2,3

Answer (score 25):

If you are using yajra laravel datatables

Just add **->addIndexColumn()**

```
return DataTables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
```

In your javascript, you can set the first row as a serial number like this

```
columns: [
            { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action' }
        ]
```

**use DT_Row_Index instead of DT_RowIndex for older yajra datatable version**

Comment: In javascript, use `DT_RowIndex` instead of `DT_Row_Index`

Comment: in yajra v.9 this will work properly if we add orderable & searchable as false

```
 { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex' , orderable: false, searchable: false}, 

```

Answer (score 6):

When using Yajra Laravel datatables

```
return DataTables::of($result)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);

"columns": [
                {
                    "data": 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false, 
                    searchable: false
                },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel **Yajra Datatables** v9.x as **Service** Implementation, I add this in **getColumns** function and works well in sorting, searching, and page changing.

```
'id' => ['title' => 'N.', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false, 'render' => function() {
            return 'function(data,type,fullData,meta){return meta.settings._iDisplayStart+meta.row+1;}';
        }],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see my code :

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl No</th>
                                <th>Invoice No</th>
                                <th>Customer</th>
                                <th>Total Price</th>
                                <th>Paid</th>
                                <th>Due</th>
                                <th>Discount</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

And the script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var i = 1;
            var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('collections') }}",
                columns: [{
                    "render": function() {
                        return i++;
                    }
                },
                    {
                        data: 'issue_no',
                        name: 'issue_no'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'customer_name',
                        name: 'customer_name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'total_order_price',
                        name: 'total_order_price'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'paid_amount',
                        name: 'paid_amount'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'due_amount',
                        name: 'due_amount'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'discount_amount',
                        name: 'discount_amount'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'action',
                        name: 'action',
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false
                    }
                ],
                createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
                    if (data['due_amount'] > 0) {
                        $('td', row).eq(4).css('background-color', '#f4511e','color','#ffffff');
                        $('td', row).eq(4).css('color','#ffffff');
                    } else {

                    }
                    $('td', row).eq(3).addClass('text-right');
                    $('td', row).eq(4).addClass('text-right');
                    $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('text-right');
                    $('td', row).eq(6).addClass('text-right');
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

In the rendering part, you can add the auto-increment field

```
{
  "render": function() {
      return i++;
     }
```

},

Answer (score 0):

simple using render function script on yajra datatable, this is my code:

```
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
            Column::make('row_number')
                    ->title('#')
                    ->render('meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;')
                    ->width(50)
                    ->orderable(false),
           ];
}
```